# mysql update trigger not working

Tags: mysql, sql

whats wrong with my MySQL trigger query

I am trying to create a trigger in which value is calculated from entry_table and update to totals table while inserting in the entry table

but it's not working on multiple queries please suggest me right method
[image: total_table]

entry_table
[image]

total table
[image]

Comment: Hm, looks like you should use the proper syntax for your UPDATE statements. Maybe the manual can be of help.

Comment: `update totals set SUB_A;` isn't a valid SQL query at all

Comment: @Alexey if i am removing ,its giving error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update totals set SUB_A =(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM ENTRY WHERE ACCOUNT='SUM_A') WHERE ACCOUNT='SUM_A';
```

Try above query.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: its saving without error but while inserting record in entry table showing #1054 - Unknown column 'ACCOUNT' in 'where clause'

Comment: Try updated answer.
Also provide entry and totals table create statement.

Comment: it's working after removing extra where clause thanx a lot